# Object is possibly null after type check (ts18047)

Tags: typescript

Some old code resurfaced and I attempted adding some TypeScript types.

Given `Memo` -

```
type Memo<T> = () => T

function memo<T>(fn: () => T): Memo<T> {
  let value: undefined | T = undefined
  return () => {
    if (value === undefined) value = fn()
    return value
  }
}
```

And `Stream` -

```
type Stream<T> = null | {
  value: T
  next: () => Stream<T>
}

function stream<T>(value: T, next: () => Stream<T>): Stream<T> {
  return {
    value,
    next: memo(next),
  }
}
```

Adding types to `map` and `filter`, I am encountering unexpected TypeScript error -

```
function map<T, U>(s: Stream<T>, fn: (t: T) => U): Stream<U> {
  if (s) {
    return stream(
      fn(s.value),
      () => map(s.next(), fn), // ✅ s is not null
    ) 
  }
  return null
}

function filter<T>(s: Stream<T>, fn: (t: T) => boolean): Stream<T> {
  while (s) {
    if (fn(s.value)) {
      return stream(
        s.value,
        () => filter(s.next(), fn), // ❌ s is possibly null 
      )
    }
    s = s.next()
  }
  return null
}
```

How can `s` be null? I thought it might have to do with the `s = ...` reassignment but other examples narrow as expected -

```
function toArray<T>(s: Stream<T>): Array<T> {
  const r: Array<T> = []
  while (s) {
    r.push(s.value) // ✅ s is not null
    s = s.next()
  }
  return r
}
```

Link to [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAshC2B7APAFQHxQLxQBQEptNUAoEgMwFcA7AY2AEtFqp4EUNdzqAuPQrMXx84SNJgDeJKFAA2EYFABuAQ1mUIfGgBMI5BtQjaoAHyipsUHXoNHpUAE4LKDlgSJQpMmQ3J5V6tBYwVbUuvqG2oQBGpbcBPYyTsAuLDEQ9gC+JNkkoJBQAMrATirw4pbUlLKypp726XykMoYAHsB87oJFJRBl4jlkVHSMzFAAzr39nI3mADRQbR38HsWl5RjCPesVXo7OrvXeymoac4mLEO18bEi4S-jnMtm5w-RMLPAqYGgLAKroXDjPhrPobdALbidZaoASYP5bUH9AFHKC+PDjQh7JIHFiTdZcahAgB06UeK26XzAJKWBEh1Hw+Cy9mSqUW1VkgwoNHeY30smAEAc4iBIKm4Pp0KacKgACNEIh5CoGWKdhhUQB3AAWDHkGKxF3RhJJZINxxxKUO+LBJtOEAWXUw-MFDhpV2AdKg3EZF2yx3GlnGxNpTOeLNx7JqXLeoxYwBUAGsICLgdsweIFrx2fBZULEeLdvYjQGAGQlxZQTAABjN3lZVvFtsCDpl8aTbvanpYAFooABGH1hi1sqpR1482NQYCIACCDgcKhAKdV6c2fDnC6X6r2tGYk0c6-ni4qOAA2gBdeza3XQIG1pLEsCUcZapsaUPeAM4IMh5nDw4ONGE4fBMDAQEoECimm-RVDmQroPmOywbmDiSEWfh3qi-54o2QbpC2HjYnWEbjGBEFcLqLodh65JKB4dEAKQTKSdpQAAhCENYfs8H5+vslosKOnK5Lu1D7shQpfngWYSQ4iHprJmDdNaZT3AR3SyeM9xQAA1P2PokKJ+5OOM1SKDg04bouuBtpBpHgZBmm4AATIyCx9lWnkGUZioQMSsiIAA5rgJlmUyQA).

---

A `const` binding fixes this particular issue -

```
function filter<T>(s: Stream<T>, fn: (t: T) => boolean): Stream<T> {
  while (s) {
    if (fn(s.value)) {
      const m = s                   // ✅ constant m
      return stream(
        m.value,
        () => filter(m.next(), fn), // ✅ m is not null
      )
    }
    s = s.next()
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: Narrowing doesn't cross function boundaries; see linked q/a for more information, or [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for the relevant issue in GitHub.

Comment: except when it does?

Comment: I'd need an example of "when it does" to know how to respond.

Comment: how about the `map` example?

Comment: It is never reassigned so narrowing is considered permanent.

Comment: The basic issue is still ms/TS#9998; `const`s narrowing persists everywhere, `let`/`var` narrowing does not, and function parameters are treated like `const`s iff they are never reassigned anywhere obvious syntactically as per [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50580#issuecomment-1239679797)